# Telerik kendo MVC subgrid in combination with edit poup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a kendo grid with a subgrid based on MVC, the data is editable using the popup mode. this all works fine,
but when I add a subrow I would like to have the related field to the parent table already filled.
My code looks like this:

```
    <script id="subGrid" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SiennInvoice.Models.InvoiceModel>()
        .Name("grid_#=ID#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
              columns.ForeignKey(c => c.IntervalType, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.IntervalTypesDdl, "Value", "Text");
              columns.Bound(c => c.Interval);
              columns.Bound(c => c.Amount);
              columns.Bound(c => c.InvoiceDate);
              columns.ForeignKey(c => c.Currency, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.CurrenciesDdl, "Value", "Text");
              columns.Bound(c => c.Done);
              columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
          })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Invoices", "OrderEdit", new { OrderId = "#=ID#" }))

            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            //.Model(model => model.Id(o => o.ID))
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(o => o.ID);
                model.Field(field => field.OrderId).DefaultValue("#=ID#");
            })
          //.Create(create => create.Action("Invoice_Create", "OrderEdit"))
          //.Update(update => update.Action("Invoice_Update", "OrderEdit"))
          //.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Invoice_Destroy", "OrderEdit"))
          //.Read(read => read.Action("Invoices_Read", "ToBeInvoiced"))
          .Create(create => create.Action("Invoices_Create", "ToBeInvoiced"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Invoices_Update", "ToBeInvoiced"))
          .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Invoices_Destroy", "ToBeInvoiced"))
        )
        .ToClientTemplate()
)
</script>
```

The issue is in the DefaultValue, I cannot use "#=ID" here like I do in the read action,
this raises an error.
I however, Can use 1,2 or 3 but I would like to have this dynamically per row.

Can someone help me with this?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm try to use this way:

1. write my own PopUp EditTemplate and include the tag

`<input type="hidden" name="OrderId" id="OrderId"/>`

2. add an event

   `.Events(events => events.Edit("function(e){e.model.OrderId='#=OrderId#';}"));`